# Problema con ApplicationDbContext en base de datos Mysql

Tags: c#, .net

Me conecto mediante Postman a una WebApi, para lo mismo genero un token de acceso que obviamente lo envio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero obtengo error al intentar obtener los paises:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'PaisController'.**

Aqui el codigo de PaisController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApiSegura.Controllers;
using WebApiSegura.Models;

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

[Authorize] // SOLO USUARIOS AUTENTICADOS

public class PaisController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public PaisController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Pais
    [HttpGet]
 

    // GET: api/Pais/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Pais>> GetPais(Guid id)
    {
        var pais = await _context.Pais.FindAsync(id);

        if (pais == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return pais;
    }

    // PUT: api/Pais/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutPais(Guid id, Pais pais)
    {
        if (id != pais.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(pais).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!PaisExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Pais
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Pais>> PostPais(Pais pais)
    {
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<Pais> entityEntry = _context.Pais.Add(pais);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetPais", new { id = pais.Id }, pais);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Pais/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Pais>> DeletePais(Guid id)
    {
        var pais = await _context.Pais.FindAsync(id);
        if (pais == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Pais.Remove(pais);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return pais;
    }

    private bool PaisExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Pais.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Y mi ApplicationDBContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApiSegura.Controllers;
using WebApiSegura.Models;

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Pais> Pais { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pais>().HasData(
            new Pais { Nombre = "España", Habitantes = 46000000 },
            new Pais { Nombre = "Alemania", Habitantes = 83000000 },
            new Pais { Nombre = "Francia", Habitantes = 65000000 },
            new Pais { Nombre = "Italia", Habitantes = 61000000 }
            );
    }
}
```

En appsettings.json tengo los datos de la base de datos:

```
{

    

    "JWT": {
      "Audience": "localhost/api",
      "ClaveSecreta": "OLAh6Yh5KwNFvOqgltw7",
      "Issuer": "localhost"
    },
 
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=apisegura"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Quisiera entender a que se debe el error, tampoco dice si fallo al conectar a la base de datos(de hecho esta creada y corriendo) o que puede ser.

Comment: ¿Has registrado y configurado tu ApplicationDbContext al inicializar los servicios?

Comment: Eso como lo haría? En qué archivo?

Comment: mostranos tu startup.cs ahi se configuran los servicios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas configurar en tu *Startup.cs* en el metodo *ConfigureServices* tu DbContext para que este disponible para inyeccion de dependencia en tu **PaisController** por ejemplo:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```

Solo agrega esta linea dentro de *ConfigureServices* del archivo *Startup.cs*

Comment: Agregue el codigo que me pasaste pero obtengo: error CS1061 en UseMySql, ya tengo incorporado el paquete MySql.Data. Buscando encontre que muchos usan Pomelo, pero no se que otra solucion habra

Comment: @Caruso que version de .Net Core estas usando?, segun la pagina de Mysql estos son los paquetes necesarios https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html

Comment: Net Core 3.1. Pero funciono como me dijiste.Muchas gracias